# In Struts2 I can't use modeldriven with validate

Tags: validation, jakarta-ee, struts2, model-driven

In the struts.xml:

```
    <action name="User_UserFormSubmit"  class="actions.UserManager">
        <result name="input" >/jsp/user_form.jsp</result>
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction"> success_register</result>
    </action>
```

My class:

```
public class UserManager extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>{

   private User user = new User();

   @Override
   public User getModel() {
    return user;
   }

   public String validate() {
    addActionError("blabla");
   }
   public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
} ...
```

then in the jsp:

```
    <s:property value="getActionErrors()"/>
```

I expect in the input result :

```
   <li> blabla </li>
```

I succefully arrived to user_form.jsp, but the actionError does not appear

I tried without the "implements ModelDriven" and it work

The model driven erase the actionErrors (I supposed)

I want to use validate and modeldriven  ¿any idea?

Comment: Have defined result type input? Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I have define "result type input" and I haven't any exception. I succefully arrived to the jsp, but the ActionErrors where erased by the model driven (I supposed)

Comment: Can you provide your configuration file struts.xml?

Comment: You are leaving something out... There should be no issues with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a big fan of model driven... but here is an example.

Before the example please note that using validate() does not make much sense in terms of ModelDriven.  The reason is that the Model should be used over several actions and so the validation should probably be consistent.  You don't use model driven just to make property names a bit shorter (to do that you use the struts2 push tag).  As such validation should be done with xml as the model is bigger than any one action. Each action which uses that model uses the Visitor validator. This validator merely looks up the xml validation file for the model. The following example however will use the validate() method in the action to save time.

The following example will use the struts2-conventions-plugin to reduce the example size (adding it to your project is simply a matter of adding one jar).

**create**: com.quaternion.action.AddUser

```
package com.quaternion.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

public class AddUser  extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>{
    User user = new User();

    @Override
    public User getModel() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(){
       if (user.age != 12) {
        super.addActionError("bla bla bla");
       }
    }  
}
```

**create**: com.quaternion.action.User

```
package com.quaternion.action;

public class User {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

**create**: /WEB-INF/content/add-user-input.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:form action="add-user">
            <s:textfield name="name"/>
            <s:textfield name="age"/>
            <s:submit/>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**create**: /WEB-INF/content/add-user-success.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Success</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Success</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**To test**:

Add */add-user-input* as the action name on your context path. If you enter an age of 12 you will get the success page, if you enter anything else you will get an action error. This has been tested to work. It is possible a typo was made, but the main thing to take away is there is an error in your application, using both conventions or xml there should be no issues with what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also validate with `@validations` too, you have access to model driven object in the validator.

```
@Action(value = "save-user")
@Validations(
    stringLengthFields = { 
        @StringLengthFieldValidator(fieldName = "name", trim = true, key = "validate.required.string.length"),
        @StringLengthFieldValidator(fieldName = "age", trim = true, key = "validate.required.string.length"),
        @StringLengthFieldValidator(fieldName = "address.addLine1", trim = true, key = "validate.required.string.length")
        })

public String save()  {
```

Comment: If you use this way you will have to repeat each validation on each method that you want to validate, please check how to validate on your model/bean side.

Comment: yes! But as far as I find I can not use validation anotations (like @Required) when I use validate, Please correct me!

Comment: You can use "@VisitorFieldValidator annotation on your getModel() method, using it the ValidationInterceptor looks for validations inside the clase of your model.

In the model side you can add "@RequiredStringValidator" annotation (for example) or any other annotation provided by the Struts core.

Comment: And yes you can use the method validate and the validation annotations in the same action without problem. The annotations are execute by the AnnotationValidationInterceptor and the validate is excuted by the DefaultWorkflowInterceptor as Struts docs says.

Comment: So the best way would be: 1- Use annotations in your action to validate common validations (required, min length, etc ...) 2- Use validate() for business validation of your model.  In this way you can still take the advantage of validation annotations and the pre-build validations while validate your model in one place (validate method)

Comment: Well, that depends absolutely of the architecture of your project. For example, in the projects that I've worked we do common validations, as you name it, in the model side, on that way each time your create an object with data from browser you'll validate it. On the other hand, we put the business rules in the business layer.